# Multithreaded GC in LLVM

Tags: multithreading, garbage-collection, llvm

I would like to implement GC for a language supporting multiple threads. There will be no shared state between threads as communication will be based on message passing. I do not care much about performance. The priority for me is to get things working.

I have read LLVM guide on writing GC: http://llvm.org/docs/GarbageCollection.html. Shadow stack approach looks very promising. The problem is, as described in the guide, shadow stack is single thread solution.
It would be ideal if I could get LLVM to create a shadow stack on per thread basis. How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using "green" threads?

Since you do not care much about performance it sounds like threads are mostly for concurrency. This can be implemented without using multiple OS-level threads at all. LLVM's existing support works fine in that case.